# ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my coding in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE TICKET (
  TICKET_NO NUMBER,
  VENUE_NO VARCHAR(3),
  TICKET_DATE   DATE,
  TICKET_PRICE NUMBER(8,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (TICKET_NO), 
    CONSTRAINT TICKET_VENUE_NO_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (VENUE_NO) REFERENCES VENUE
);
```

This is error stated:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE TABLE TICKET (
TICKET_NO   NUMBER,
VENUE_NO VARCHAR(3),
TICKET_DATE DATE,
TICKET_PRICE NUMBER(8,2),
PRIMARY KEY (TICKET_NO), 
 CONSTRAINT TICKET_VENUE_NO_FK
FOREIGN KEY (VENUE_NO) REFERENCES VENUE)
Error at Command Line:8 Column:13
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type
02267. 00000 -  "column type incompatible with referenced column type"
*Cause:    The datatype of the referencing column is incompatible with the
```

What wrong with my coding?

Comment: The error mesage says it all. Table VENUE's primary key is not compatible with VARCHAR(3).

Comment: Can you please post the DDL for CREATE TABLE VENUE

Answer (score 4):

Check that the VENUE_NO field in the VENUE table is of the same type as in this table, i.e. VARCHAR(3).

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the data types match between the `TICKET.VENUE_NO` column and the `VENUE.VENUE_NO` column.

Answer (score 0):

It is often seen in the `FOREIGN KEY (attr1) REFERENCES attr2`. You need to check the data type you reference, it should keep the same as the previous table. Such as `varchar` and `char`.

Answer (score -1):

It could be due to non correspondence of data types. Make sure that `venue_no` has the same type in both tables.

Comment: You don't have to scream

Comment: Sorry. Cap lock was on.. Didn't notice until i clicked send.